# Move the legend item itself in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot and I can move the legend label with `label.vjust` in `guide` but that only moved the label and not the item itself.

Here is my code for the plot:

```
b <- ggplot(data = subset(sub.girders.plot, Sample == "CSI"), 
   aes(x = Girder, y = `Moment LLDF`, fill = factor(S,levels = c("9","12","15")))) +  theme_classic() +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75),
                 fatten = 1, lwd = 0.2) +
    stat_summary(fun = mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=0.5, stroke = 0.2,
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) + 
    stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', linetype=1, width=0.5, lwd = 0.2, 
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(sub.girders.plot, Sample == "Rigid Rotation Method"), 
               aes(shape = Sample), stroke = 0.3, size = 2, 
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5, col='gray', lwd=0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2.5, col='gray', lwd=0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 3.5, col='gray', lwd=0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 4.5, col='gray', lwd=0.2) +
  annotate("segment", x=-Inf, xend=Inf, y=-Inf, yend=-Inf, size = 0.35)+
  annotate("segment", x=-Inf, xend=-Inf, y=-Inf, yend=Inf, size = 0.35) +
  annotate("segment", x=Inf, xend=Inf, y=-Inf, yend=Inf, size = 0.35) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(8)) +
      labs(x = element_blank(), shape = element_blank(), 
           fill = "Analytical Data with \n Girder Spacing (ft) of:") +
    theme(legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.position = "bottom", 
          axis.text.y = element_text(size=8, colour="black"),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, colour="black", angle=40, vjust=0.6),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size=8, colour="black", vjust=0.5, margin = margin(0,4,0,-6)),
          axis.line=element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.2),
          legend.text = element_text(size=8, margin = margin(0,5,0,0)),
          legend.title = element_text(size=8, margin = margin(0,2,0,0)),
          strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
          strip.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 0.4),
          legend.spacing.x = unit(0.1, 'cm'), legend.spacing.y = unit(0.1, 'cm'),
          legend.background = element_blank(), legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 0.2)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(label.position = "bottom", label.hjust = 0.8, title.vjust = 0.8),
         shape = guide_legend(keywidth = unit(3, "mm"),keyheight = unit(3.5, "mm"), label.vjust = -0.5)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(UG), ncol = 2)
```

This is how the plot looks now:

[image]

I would like to make two edits to this graph:

1. move the star item down.
2. make the dot in my boxplot legend item smaller (or remove from the legend item). At the moment, when i make the point size bigger in `geom_point` this dot in the legend also gets larger.

Desired output:

[image]

**EDIT**

I was able to change the dot in the boxplot `fill` by:

```
. . . + guides(fill = guide_legend(label.position = "bottom", label.hjust = 0.8, title.vjust = 0.8, 
                         override.aes = list(shape = c(23))),
     shape = guide_legend(keywidth = unit(3, "mm"), keyheight = unit(3, "mm"), 
                          label.vjust = -1))
```

I am still looking for a method to move the legend item down with the label

Answer (score -2):

Hiding the dot should be easy.

Add show.legend= FALSE to the geom_point.

`geom_point(aes(...), show.legend = FALSE)`
EDIT:

Actually your dot is from the stat_summary, so add it there.

Comment: That removes the legend item for `Rigid Rotation Method` as well. That is not what I am looking for.

Comment: "Controlling legend appearance in ggplot2 with override.aes" https://aosmith.rbind.io/2020/07/09/ggplot2-override-aes/

Comment: That link will let you adjust the size.  I haven't tested, but perhaps adjusting dodge fixes the position too?

Comment: label.vjust is what needs modified